Woocommerce custom checkout place order button + Cartflows
I need to change submit button text. I am using CartFlows plugin on WordPress with Woocommerce.
In CartFlows setting I can add "custom text on place order button" but it does not work. It shows but when page is fully loaded then it disappears and text is default again.
Code of button:
<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Kupuję i przyciągam obfitość!" data-value="Kupuję i przyciągam obfitość!">Zapłać</button>

As you can see value should be "Kupuję..." but it shows as "Zapłać".
I tried using the following code in functions.php:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_place_order', 'wc_custom_order_button_text' ); 
function wc_custom_order_button_text() 
    return __( 'Place Donation', 'woocommerce' ); 
}

but it does not work. How can I solve this?

"It shows but when page is fully loaded then it desappears and text is default again." - sounds like it might probably get replaced by some JavaScript then.

yeah, but I have no idea how to solve it.

If JavaScript is able to restore the default text, then it must have access to this default text somehow. I'd start by checking the source code of the page for the default text (or parts thereof), to try and see in what other locations it might occur. (And once you found it somewhere, you can then investigate how to change it in that location as well.)
